# AWS CDK Getting Error when try to initialize a new VPC with private isolated subnet used in Fargate Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, aws-cdk, aws-fargate

AWS CDK Getting Error when try to initialize a new VPC with private isolated subnet used in Fargate Cluster. (@aws-cdk/ -- @1.174.0 - Version).

```
this.vpc = new ec2.Vpc(this, `horizonCloudVpc`, {
    cidr: '10.0.0.0/16',
    vpcName: `horizonCloudVpc-${envName}`,
    enableDnsHostnames: true,
    enableDnsSupport: true,
    maxAzs: 2,
    subnetConfiguration: [
      {
        name: 'public-subnet',
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC,
        cidrMask: 24,
      },
      {
        name: 'isolated-subnet',
        subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PRIVATE_ISOLATED,
        cidrMask: 24,
      },
    ]
});

const clusterAdmin = new Role(this, 'eksClusterMasterRole', {
    roleName: `clusterMasterRole-${envName}`,
    assumedBy: new AccountRootPrincipal(),
});

const cluster = new eks.FargateCluster(this, 'horizonCloudEks', {
  version: eks.KubernetesVersion.V1_21,
  vpc: vpc,
  clusterName: `horizonCloudEks-${envName}`,
  endpointAccess: eks.EndpointAccess.PUBLIC,
  mastersRole: clusterAdmin,
});
```

Error from Deploy -

```
/home/runner/work/horizon/horizon/cdk/node_modules/@aws-cdk/aws-ec2/lib/vpc.ts:606
      throw new Error(`There are no '${subnetType}' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: ${availableTypes}`);
            ^
Error: There are no 'Private' subnet groups in this VPC. Available types: Isolated,Deprecated_Isolated,Public
```

I might think it requires a `PRIVATE_WITH_NAT` subnet also.

Thanks!

Comment: please don't paste text as screenshots.   Copy the text itself and paste it as text

Comment: Is this the complete code of your CDK app? Are you using the VPC in any way?

Comment: Done, as @gshpychka says, it might be related because I am using the Fargate cluster with this VPC. But, I Haven't found a source that Fargate cluster requires it.

Comment: Did the answer help?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because EKS is trying to make the cluster use Private and Public subnets in the VPC, and there are no Private subnets in it.

From the [`eks.FargateCluster` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_eks.FargateCluster.html#vpcsubnets):

> vpcSubnets?
> Type: SubnetSelection[] (optional, default: All public and private subnets)

To change this default behavior, change the `vpcSubnets` constructor prop to the appropriate value. For example, to make the cluster only use Public subnets:

```js
vpcSubnets: [{ subnetType: ec2.SubnetType.PUBLIC }]
```

Comment: Farget only works with private subnets, at least that'd be the case for EKS.

Comment: @mino that is not true, it also works with Public or Isolated subnets.

Comment: According to the documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/fargate.html.

"Pods that run on Fargate are only supported on private subnets (with NAT gateway access to AWS services, but not a direct route to an Internet Gateway), so your cluster's VPC must have private subnets available."

Comment: That's for EKS pods that require internet access.